# TFS build failed with .target file not able to copy file its too long?

Tags: c#, .net, tfs, tfsbuild

> C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\OfficeTools\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.targets (524): Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll" to ".\bin\Release\app.publish\Application Files\SI.TemplateDesignerOffice2007_4_1_9080_0199\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.dll.deploy".

The specified path, file name, or both are too long. The fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Comment: What is your question? You have an error message; you need to troubleshoot it. If you've attempted to do so and you're stuck, you need to provide more context on when the error occurs and what you've done to attempt to solve it.

Comment: Question seems "clearish", he can't get his publish to work and the error is the pathname is too long.

Comment: Is this a VSTS build? Otherwise where does TFS come into it?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your publish folder, remove it from your bin and put in somewhere higher in your directory structure, like besides your src folder or something.

Comment: Why the down-vote, this will insure that the fully qualified file name must be less than 260 characters, and the directory name must be less than 248 characters.

Answer (score 0):

That's the Microsoft limited.

There is a thread talking about this :
[MSBuild should handle paths longer than MAX_PATH](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/53)

So, I can think of is that just try to shorten the path, you can refer to below articles to troubleshoot the issue:

- [Publishing Builds to a Deep Drop Location](http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/publishing_buil_1.html)
- [Microsoft Removes 260-Character Path Length Limit in Windows 10
  Redstone](https://news.softpedia.com/news/microsoft-removes-260-characters-path-length-limit-in-windows-10-redstone-504596.shtml)

Comment: @Mr. N. Das Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Comment: I'm facing this issue while release using TFS 2015

Comment: I found Microsoft has fixed the issue. Related info is posted